# Listing Website Articles Properly

Tags: php, mysql

So I've been using PHP to list my website's articles via MySQL. The problem is, the posts are supposed to be listed with newest at the top, but instead oldest posts are at the top. How can I change this. Here is a snippet of source code:

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
   <div class="container">
      <h2 class="title"><a href=""><?php echo htmlspecialchars($post['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></h2>
      <p class="date"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($post['date'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></p>
      <div class="body">
      <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($post['content'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <?php endforeach; ?>

try {

   $sql = 'SELECT id, title, date, content FROM post';
   $result = $pdo->query($sql);

} catch (PDOException $e) {

   $error = 'Error connecting to database server: ' . $e->getMessage();
   exit();

}
```

Comment: show us the MySQL query

Comment: in your sql use `DESC` in the `ORDER BY` section - so `ORDER BY publish_date DESC`

Comment: Off topic, but you should be using `<article>` for "articles." Check out: http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your initial query, be sure to include the line

```
ORDER BY $column
```

and then either

```
ASC
```

or

```
DESC
```

Where $column references the date column, I would presume.